# Fill a datatable with products from the magento SOAP api

Tags: c#, api, magento, soap, datatable

I am working on a Stock Update application for my magento website.
I already have the api installed and it works correctly.
What i want is to fill a datatable with all the product sku's from my website.
this is my log in code:
`String mlogin = mservice.login("user", "pasword");
 label1.Text = Convert.ToString(mlogin);`

Thanks.